# Login with Blazor Webassembly and Active Directory

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, blazor-webassembly

I am working with Blazor WEBASSEMBLY in Visual Studio 20222 and Net 6. I need to login, validating that the user is in Active Directory, active and has a specific security group assigned. Is it possible to do this? Someone have any example code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Authentication and/or authorization? you need to reveal your goals. Besides, Blazor WebAssembly runs in the browser side sandbox, so if your goal is to hide certain features from a user based on authorization, it is technically invalid as the user can enable the feature on his/her own without much effort.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/coding-flamingo/BlazorWasmWithAADAuth

Comment: That is a tutorial for Azure Active Directory, not Standard Active Directory. I am having trouble finding anything regarding Blazor and standard AD...